# Python code applying to multiple files or folder

Tags: python, email

I am quite new to Python and I have created some simple Python code (below) to print (or return) the body, subject and from email address of a .eml file. This works fine. However, how can i apply this code to a folder of .eml files?

```
import email

fp = open('C:\emlfiles\TEST_00000.eml')

msg = email.message_from_file(fp)

subject = msg.get('subject')
subject = str(subject)
fromAdd = msg.get('from')
fromAdd = str(fromAdd)
payload = msg.get_payload()
if type(payload) == type(list()) :
    payload = payload[0] 
if type(payload) != type('') :
    payload = str(payload)

print subhec + fromAdd + payload
```

Comment: read up on python functions.  The first step is to rurn this code into a function which accepts the filename as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in a for loop using `os.listdir`:

```
import email

infolder = "C:\\emlfiles\\"
for infile in os.listdir(infolder):
    fp = open(os.path.join(infolder, infile))
    msg = email.message_from_file(fp)
    # etc
```

Perhaps better would be to wrap that code in a function and then call it:

```
def process_email(infile):
    fp = open(infile)
    msg = email.message_from_file(fp)
    subject = msg.get('subject')

infolder = "C:\\emlfiles\\"
for infile in os.listdir(infolder):
    process_email(os.path.join(infolder, infile))
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), it does what you want.

Comment: I'd +1 that. But you you do make a lot of file manipulations, the very small yet very wonderful path.py library is your friends. It's only one file (https://github.com/jaraco/path.py) and it's f**ing brillant to be able to recurse on all dirs by doing `for d in path('/your/path').walkdirs()'`